# Find unique substring of String s with given length

Tags: python, string

I am trying to solve this question. For example, the string equals "caaab" and the length K=2, the return substrings should be "aa","ab","ca" in an alphabetic order. I prefer the solution in python

Comment: Might you prefer to think about the solution in python before posting here as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_str = 'caaab'
k = 2

unique_substrings = set(input_str[i: i + k] for i in range(len(input_str) - k + 1))
sorted_substrings = sorted(unique_substrings)

print(sorted_substrings)
```